# React Resolve all promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to wait to resolve a 1st promise, then 2 async promises, then fire off logic working from the all the prior promises.

How can I accomplish this? This is what I have so far, and the `axios.all(promises)` does not wait for the prior 2 async promises.

```
fetchData = () => {
    let promises = [];

    axios.get("/api1.json")
        .then((response) => {
          //do logic 1
        })
        .then( () => { 

            promises.push(
                () => { return
                    //data for components
                    axios.get("/api21.json")
                        .then(response => { //do logic 2.1 }) 
                }   
            )           
            ,
            promises.push(
                () => { return
                    axios.get("/api22.json")
                        .then(response => { //do logic 2.2 })
                }
            )

        })

        axios.all(promises).then( //do final logic 3 after logic 2.1 and 2.2 have performed ))
    }
```

Comment: your `axios.all` will fire before you've pushed the promises in... you have to put it in the same block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the first request, then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for the last two promises to resolve before you do anything with the three responses.

**Example**

```
fetchData = () => {
  axios.get("/api1.json").then(response1 => {
    Promise.all([axios.get("/api21.json"), axios.get("/api22.json")]).then(
      ([response2, response3]) => {
        console.log(response1, response2, response3);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The probem is that you are trying to run axios promise to fast, also the axios.get is too deep in the function. Could you try this one:

```
fetchData = () => {

axios.get("/api1.json")
    .then((response) => {
      //do logic 1
    })
    .then( () => { 
        return axios.all([
            //data for components
            axios.get("/api21.json")
                .then(response => { //do logic 2.1 }),       
            axios.get("/api22.json")
                .then(response => { //do logic 2.2 })
        ]);
    })
    .then( // do final logic 3);
}
```